# Extract date from django query

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have a query with the date filter.

```
queryset=Model.objects.filter(order_created_on__gte='2018-10-10')
```

It constructs a query like this -

```
 "Model"."order_created_on" >= 2018-10-10 00:00:00+05:30
```

Which gives an error for that '00:00:00+05:30' when I qun the query. The queryset populates the data properly, but I want it to run via query.

An alternative is to use 'order_created_on__date__gte' but its giving an error, thinkso date filter is not available with __gte.

Another alternative is to construct my filters such - 'order_created_on__range=['2018-10-10 00:00:00+05:30']'.

Any other alternative available?

Comment: What do you mean with "I do not want it to run via query"?

Comment: I want to run via query. There is a mechanism which executes the query to generate a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
queryset=Model.objects.filter(order_created_on__year__gte=2018, order_created_on__month__gte=10, order_created_on__date__gte=10)
```

or simply

```
queryset= Model.objects.filter(order_created_on__gte=datetime.date(2010, 10, 10))
```

Comment: It attaches the time zone to the query everytime

Comment: Did you try queryset= Model.objects.filter(order_created_on__gte=datetime.date(2010, 10, 10)) ?

Comment: order_created_on__date__gte
This statement gives an error - 'expected string or bytes-like object'
Its actually order_created_on__day__gte

Comment: Update your question with model structure

Comment: Its simple,
Any queryset(all the answers discussed above including datetime object for comparison, splitting it into date,year,month) with order_created_on has the text ''order_created_on > yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00+5:30" in its actual query.